# Querying via Service Bus

Tags: service, bus

Is it recommended to also do querying via a Service Bus? As I see it, you should only send fire and forget commands/events.

What is your opinion and/or experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service bus is not only suited to "fire and forget" scenarios. In fact it can be used in many others like "request response". But in contrast to classic remote procedure calls or invocations, service bus provides means to decouple actual requester from actual responder. And that opens the door for easier scalability and/or improved resilience.

There are plenty of posts, articles and books written on the subject of messaging and service bus patterns, and will provide valuable insights and ideas. Just look for service bus or message queue integration, patterns.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by queruing? Retrieving data from database? Aggregating multiplie responses from several services? All those things are done quite good with Service Bus. Some specific products like WebSphere ESB or Oracle Service Bus offer ability to generate database adapters which can retrieve data from tables or call stored procedures.